# ELMAH - Email not received in production environment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, elmah

I have integrated ELMAH library for logging the error. I have integrated email code for getting error list but unable to get those errors. Can anyone help me for same. Below is my configuration code in web.config

**Web.config File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>

  <elmah>

    <errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/ElmahLog" />
    <errorMail from="error@devtracker.com"
     to="ankitkanojia.rs@gmail.com"
     subject="Devtracker - Error occurs"
     async="true" />

    <security allowRemoteAccess="false" />
  </elmah>


  <location path="elmah.axd" inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
      </httpHandlers>     
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="ELMAH" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Everything is integrated and work perfectly, seems like only automatic email sends functionality not working.

Comment: The answer from @Suchit is correct. But for future issues like this, you could use the [Web.config Validator](https://elmah.io/tools/configvalidator/).

Comment: @ThomasArdal thank you so much for your input, will take care now onwards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After going through your question, I've found that you just forgot to add an email setting. Add the below lines in your web.config. Make sure to change the hostname, port, username, and password.

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
        <network host="host address" port="12345" userName="username here" password="password here"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```